# Cannot find the response URL to properly register my PowerApps App on Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerapps

I'm trying to implement RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) on a project that uses PowerApps. I've followed the steps depicted here: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/implementing-role-based-permission/

Those steps are for registering a custom connector inside Azure AD for PowerApps, which enables me to use the GraphAPI for developing RBAC. 
On the article, it says that I should copy the response URL that its shown on the error screen to the "Reponse URL" field of Azure AD App Registration. But I have no such thing. The error screen I get is this one, which has no Response URL: [image]

How can I find my Apps's response URL so I can properly configure the conector in Azure AD?

Comment: The error message no longer includes the reply URL from the request. If you sign out from Azure AD, and you try again, *before* typing in username and password, do you see a `redirect_uri` parameter in the URL address bar?

Comment: I do see it. It is https%3a%2f%2fbrazil-001.consent.azure-apim.net%2f.
I'm guessing %3a is a colon and %2f is a forward slash. I've tried those in the Azure AD redirect URLs and it didn't work.

Comment: You can enter it as `https://brazil-001.consent.azure-apim.net/` in AAD. That's just the way it has to encode for it to be sent across in a query parameter.

Comment: @juunas I entered the way you mentioned, but to no success.

Comment: That's interesting.. Sometimes it can take a moment for stuff to update though. Also make sure the client_id in the URL matches the client id/application id of the app you are modifying.

Comment: Everything matches perfectly. I haven't mentioned, but I'm using the "demo" tenant that microsoft provides for partners. It should work the same, right?

Comment: Solved, see bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I was misreading the URL. The URL on the login screen was https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=bb9f3ec5-c2ad-4ed4-a46b-4472838fe747&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fbrazil-001.consent.azure-apim.net%2fredirect&resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.microsoft.com%2f&prompt=select_account&state=94054d67-5f50-47ce-919b-e450c965c0f8

You have to inspect it really close and you may see what @Philippe said: Look at the `redirect_uri` field, but if you watch closely, you can see that after the ending (i.e: "apim.net") there's an encoded character (%2f) which represents a forward slash. After that, comes a string ('redirect') which completes the URL and made the connector work.

So, long story short, get a fresh set of eyes when inspecting sketchy URL's